# Docker is not exposing application outside container when used host network mode however it works well within container

Tags: docker, redis, docker-for-windows

I have a spring boot application which calls redis internally .
I have redis running on 6379 inside docker container (also be accessed outside container through redis client)
But When I expose the application as below it complains that redis connection failure . 
Running on 8086

**docker run -d --name containerName -p 8086:8086 containerName:version**
But Application is accessible from browser as http://localhost:8086 
However when run like below with --net=host it works perfectly fine with warning as 
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

**docker run --rm -it -d --net=host --publish-all=true --name containerName containerName:version**

But application is not accessible from browser http://localhost:8086

**Exception stack trace**

Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:282)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:134)

**Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)**
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

**Note: I am Running docker container on windows machine**

Comment: `--net=host` disables the entire Docker networking stack, including inter-container communications; it's rarely necessary for typical applications.  If the application works without this setting I'd just delete it.

Comment: Application works but while calling to redis (which is also deployed in same Docker container) it breaks with above error. and when put --net=host application is no more accessible from browser . I want application to be accessible from browser

Comment: Typically you'd run data storage layers like Redis in separate containers.  (Do you want to restart Redis every time you update the application code, or should a cache survive restarts?  If you scale the application to multiple replicas, do you also want multiple Redises?)  `--net=host` is unnecessary here and you can access the application from the browser using a `docker run -p` option.

Comment: Yeah Ideally redis should be shared among containers and there is a separate redis . I could solve the problem with below solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have redis and application container running seperately 
so here is the solution

1: redis is running on 6379
docker run --rm -it --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis

2: My service which is using redis under the hood needs to configure redis host as spring.redis.host=redis Here 
redis is nothing but the name of redis container

docker run --rm -d --link redis --name reader -p 8086:8086 imageName:version

I can access the application from browser http://localhost:8086 
here --link redis does mapping of redis host.